# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I get some exceptions on my Android project. When I start the project, I get these exceptions. App doesn't crash on emulator. But on Google play developer console, there are lots of crash because of these exceptions

I tried everything. Now I tried to get rid of this problem with using  androidX and com.android.support but didn't work!
Also, there is no answer on stack overflow to solve the issue.

***Here it is error message I get***

> 2019-07-08 20:53:41.628 15998-15998/com.packete name I/zygote: Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.packete
>   name-LZ0pkpz1KqBv7BPInTJnWw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.packete
>   name-LZ0pkpz1KqBv7BPInTJnWw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
>
> 2019-07-08 20:53:41.628 15998-15998/com.packete name I/zygote:     at
>   java.lang.Class
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String)
>   (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125) 2019-07-08 20:53:41.629
>   15998-15998/com.packete name I/zygote: Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.packete
>   name-LZ0pkpz1KqBv7BPInTJnWw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.packete
>   name-LZ0pkpz1KqBv7BPInTJnWw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
>
> 2019-07-08 20:53:41.629 15998-15998/com.packete name I/zygote:     at
>   java.lang.Class
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String)
>   (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
>
> 2019-07-08 20:53:41.630 15998-15998/com.packete name I/zygote: Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.packete
>   name-LZ0pkpz1KqBv7BPInTJnWw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.packete
>   name-LZ0pkpz1KqBv7BPInTJnWw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
>
> 2019-07-08 20:53:41.630 15998-15998/com.packete name I/zygote:     at
>   java.lang.Class
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String)
>   (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
>
> 2019-07-08 20:53:42.011 15998-15998/com.packete name I/zygote: Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.webkit.TracingController" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.android.chrome-feJOv4zSelnFLK27fJNkiw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.chrome-feJOv4zSelnFLK27fJNkiw==/lib/x86,
>   /data/app/com.android.chrome-feJOv4zSelnFLK27fJNkiw==/base.apk!/lib/x86,
>   /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
>
> 2019-07-08 20:53:42.011 15998-15998/com.packete name I/zygote:     at
>   java.lang.Class
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String)
>   (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)

Comment: This question is not duplicate! I already know that there are other topics and they don't provide any solution!

Answer (score 1):

fixed by: put following into build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == "com.android.support") {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion "26.+"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In case you're using androidx:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == "androidx") {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion "${targetSdk}.+"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried it before when I was searching but it didn't work.

Comment: tempted to -1 but it probably worked for someone @Dasharath Singh Bajroliya but I hate when people -1.  They should remove that feature.  Anyways, API 24, this doesn't seem to help :(.  thanks for posting though.